# How to display string found in title except exception list in SQL

Tags: sql, regex, database, oracle

I have following scenario

"Original" word found in Title column except below  exceptions

sample column(title) values  like -

- Original Motion Picture
- Amazing Grace (Original Broadway Cast
               Recording)

exception list:

```
 Original%Cast ,Original%Broadway, Original%Motion, Original%Score, Original%Sound, Original%Game ,Original%TV, Original%Television, Original%Off, Original%Series,
```

I have written sample query like this

```
  select  count(1)
    from table_name
    where product_id = :PRODUCT_ID
    and instr(upper(title),'ORIGINAL') > 0
    and a
(
title not like '%Original%Cast%'
--or title not like 'Original%Broadway'
--or title not like ....

);
```

Please suggest the query with regular expression  as shown list `in('%Original%Cast%','Original%Broadway','....)` in clause

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
WITH table_name AS (SELECT 'The Original Case' title FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 'The First Case' title FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 'The Super Case' title FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 'The Super Case - Original Cast Recording' title FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 'The Super Case - Original Broadway Show' title FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 'The Super Case - Original Motion Picture' title FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 'The Super Case - Original Score' title FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 'The Super Case - Original Soundtrack' title FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 'The Super Case - Original Video Game' title FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 'The Super Case - Original TV show' title FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 'The Super Case - Original television show' title FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 'The Super Case - Original off-site production' title FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 'The Super Case - Original theatre series' title FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 'The TV Original Case' title FROM dual)
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
WHERE  NOT regexp_like(title, 'original.*(cast|broadway|motion|score|sound|game|tv|television|off|series)', 'i')
AND    regexp_like(title, 'original', 'i');

TITLE
---------------------------------------------
The Original Case
The TV Original Case
```

The first regexp_like looks for a pattern of "original" followed by any character, then followed by either cast, broadway, ...., or series. The `i` in the modifier parameter means the search is case insensitive. Then we add the NOT in front of it to discount rows with that pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You should go with:

```
select  count(1)
from table_name
where product_id = :PRODUCT_ID
and instr(upper(title),'ORIGINAL') > 0
and 
(
title not like '%Original%Cast%'
or title not like 'Original%Broadway'
or title not like ....
....
)
```

Please notice that the `not like` statements are in separate bracket group.

Comment: Thanks for the query .But i need the query with regular expressions REGEXP_INSTR()

Comment: Sorry mate, in your original question you had "Please suggest the query with or without regexp in sql." at the end...